# Notation for a vector which is an expansion of another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Assume $\mathbf{x}=(1,5,7,9)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(1,5,7,9,20,12)$.
My questions are:

1. Is there any formal notation that reflects the relationship between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$? Is this possible to write $\mathbf{x} \subset \mathbf{y}$?
2. Is there any formal notation that allows the "concatenation" operator among vectors? I mean something like
   $\mathbf{x} + (20,12) = \mathbf{y}$.

Comment: If you find that you need such notation when writing something or solving an exercise, you can always declare it and then use it. For instance "if $x\in\mathbb{R}^n, y\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for $m\geq n$ such that $x_i=y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, we will denote this by $x\subseteq y$" (or any other notation you choose to invent). Similarly for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be a field, you can consider the inclusion $K^{n}\hookrightarrow K^{n+m}$ such that $x\mapsto(x,0,\dots0)$, that is you see $K^{n}$ as a vector subspace of dimension $n$ of $K^{n+m}$, but I don't think that there is a notion as $x\subset y$.

For the second, you can describe $K^{n+k}$ as $K^{n}\oplus K^{k}$, in that case $y=(x,z)$, $x\in K^{n}$ and $z=(20,12)\in K^{m}$.